# retrieve list attribute

Tags: jquery

Hi All
if i assign an attribute to list like this:

```
<ul type_code=27>
```

how can i get this value(ul type_code value ) if i know that the id of li=10(`<li id=10>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this also:

```
var code = $('#li-id').closest('ul').attr('type_code');
```

Please note: the "10" as the value of id attribute may not work on other browser.

Comment: i don't think so this is invallid id

Comment: @Vivek: `li-id` isn't an invalid ID. The OP's `10` is invalid for use with CSS (it's fine for HTML). Or did you mean `type_code` is an invalid attribute? If so, you're right; see my answer for an alternative. @jerjer: +1, btw.

Answer (score 2):

<s>The ID you give ("10()") is an invalid ID attribute (IDs can't start with a digit).</s> Sorry, [IDs used with **CSS**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) can't start with a digit; [HTML ones can](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute) if you're not going to use them with CSS. But with jQuery, you use CSS selectors a lot, so best to stick to the CSS rules.

*[**Edit**: I was using [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), but [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is better because it stops looking as soon as it's found the first match. Please [upvote jerjer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458938/retrieve-list-attribute/4458993#4458993) for that.]*

In any case, let's say the LI has the ID "fred":

```
var code = $("#fred").closest("ul").attr("type_code");
```

E.g., with this HTML:

```
<ul type_code=27>
    <li id='fred'>...</li>
</ul>
```

...the above code will set `code` to "27". [Live example](http://jsbin.com/axuhu4/3)

Note, though, that creating your own attribute values means your HTML won't [validate](http://validator.w3.org/). It's a popular practice, though, so much so that it's specifically catered for now in HTML5: Any attribute with the prefix `data-` will validate. So updating the above:

HTML:

```
<ul data-type-code=27>
    <li id='fred'>...</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript w/jQuery:

```
var code = $("#fred").closest("ul").attr("data-type-code");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/axuhu4/4)